# Eclipse 'Syntax error on token ",", Expression expected after this token', where is my syntax wrong?

Tags: java, eclipse, object, syntax-error

```
package MainFunction;


public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Gun m_one = new Gun("M1", 30, ["Bleeding"], "semi-auto", ".15 cal", "lead", 8);
    System.out.println("Java Works.");
}

}
```

There is a syntax error in m_one. It says:
Syntax error on token ",", Expression expected after this token

I'm not understanding where this is coming from. Here is my constructor:

```
package MainFunction;




 public class Weapon {
    Weapon(String name, int damage, String[] effects){
        this.name = name;
        this.damage = damage;
        this.effects = effects;
    }
    private int damage;
    public String name;
    private String[] effects;
    public void addEffect(String effect){
        effects[effects.length] = effect;
    }
}
    class Gun extends Weapon {
    private String type;
    public String name;
    private int damage;
    public String[] effects;
    private String ammoType;
    private String bulletMaterial;
    private int barrelLength;
    private String fireType;
    Gun( String name, int damage, String[] effects, String fireType, String ammoType, String bulletMaterial, int barrelLength) {
        super(name, damage, effects);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.name = name;
        this.damage = damage;
        this.effects = effects;
        this.fireType = fireType;
        this.ammoType = ammoType;
        this.type = "ranged";
        this.bulletMaterial = bulletMaterial;
        this.barrelLength = barrelLength;
    }

}



class Sword extends Weapon {
    private String type;
    public String name;
    private int damage;
    public String[] effects;
    private int bladeLength;
    private int hiltLength;
    private String bladeMaterial;
    Sword(String name, int damage, String[] effects, int barrelLength, int hiltLength, String bladeMaterial){
        super(name, damage, effects);
        this.name = name;
        this.damage = damage;
        this.effects = effects;
        this.type = "melee";    
        this.bladeLength = bladeLength;
        this.hiltLength = hiltLength;
        this.bladeMaterial = bladeMaterial;
    }
}
```

The constructor returns no errors, yet when I use it it does. What is the problem?

Comment: Can you add the exact error message please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are attempting to create and pass an array of strings with this expression:

```
["Bleeding"]
```

However, that is not the Java syntax for creating an array.  You must explicitly create the array, specifying the type, along with braces `{}` to contain the content.

```
new String[] {"Bleeding"}
```

You may have more than one element if you wish:

```
new String[] {"Bleeding", "Damaging"};
```

Also, later on in `Weapon`'s `addEffect` method, you attempt to length the array by assigning an element beyond the length of the array.

```
effects[effects.length] = effect;
```

In Java, arrays have a fixed size once created, so this will throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.  If you need a variable-length array, replace the `String[]` with a `List<String>`.  First, in the constructor:

```
Weapon(String name, int damage, List<String> effects){
```

Then when declaring `effects`:

```
List<String> effects;
```

Then when defining `addEffect`:

```
effects.add(effect);
```

Instead of creating an array in `main`, you'll need to create an implementation of `List` and pass it in.

```
List<String> effects = new ArrayList<>();
effects.add("Bleeding");
effects.add("Damaging");
Gun m_one = new Gun("M1", 30, effects, "semi-auto", ".15 cal", "lead", 8);
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that out. I'm new to Java.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use curly brackets instead of square ones in your declaration of `m_one`, surrounding "Bleeding".